# What justified getting bigger vacuum pump for HVAC?

Tags: hvac, tools, vacuum-pump

I have noticed HVAC vacuum pumps come in CFM ranging 3-10 (maybe wider). What determines whether you need more CFM, is it the size of your system (tons) or the poundage of refrigerant, the length of lineset or perhaps the vertical difference between the low and high point in your system. Can a smaller pump do the same a big pump does, just slower?

Comment: it is a tool, not a part of an HVAC system

Comment: @Ruskes you use a vacuum pump to evacuate the system before purging it and then before charging it.

Comment: I do not know where you live, but doing that is Verboten in USA

Comment: @RMDman it is about tools. i edited the tags

Comment: retracted my close vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even HVAC pros often carry a relatively small vacuum pump. A larger pump may be needed to quickly evacuate a very large system, but if the system is sealed and the pump is working properly, even a very low capacity vacuum pump will evacuate the system, and likely at the same speed as a smaller pump. What's more critical for most purposes is how hard of a vacuum the pump can reach. The difference between a 150 micron vacuum and a 15 micron vacuum is significant in terms of ability to evacuate moisture and contaminants. For more on this topic, there are a number of excellent topics on the HVAC Talk forums. You may also want to look at the micron spec needed for your applications, as that can't be fixed by running the pump longer.

Comment: what is a relatively small vacuum pump? 5 CFM ?

Comment: Some of the pros on HVAC Talk carry a 1.5 CFM. One of the pro manufacturers will sell you a 1.35 CFM unit. Another pro brand's best seller is a 5 CFM unit. In most cases the key part is that they are two stage pumps that can draw a high vacuum, though you can get away with a single stage pump if you're patient. It's hard to pull even 1 CFM through a Schrader valve so in practical terms the bigger units don't make much of a difference for most service.

Comment: do you think the length of lineset and the vertical difference between the high and low points matter?

Comment: No. Or at least not at residential or small commercial scale.

Comment: "It's hard to pull even 1 CFM through a Schrader valve" that is why it is a good practice to remove the shrader core

Comment: The valve itself is a pretty small orifice even with the core gone.